# Opening .vrt file with rasterio in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I have 3 raster files (`.tiff` files) which are geographically 3 consecutive tiles  of a particular area. I am trying to make a `.vrt` file of 2 out of these 3 files using the `gdalbuildvrt` python command. The issue I am facing is suppose if I am making a `.vrt` file (named `test.vrt`) of the first 2 files (say file 1 & 2) and opening it with `rasterio` python, it's opening correctly. Subsequently, I want to create a `.vrt` file of the new file combinations (say file 1 & 3) and overwrite the old `.vrt` file (`test.vrt`) with this file combination and try to open it with `rasterio` python. The problem I am facing now is it's still displaying the the `.vrt` file with the old file combinations (having files 1 & 2 and not files 1 & 3). The code which I used till now is:

```py
import rasterio 
import rasterio.plot

from osgeo import gdal

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
test_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt', [r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_58_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif', r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_60_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif'], options=vrt_options)

test_vrt = None

raster_vrt = rasterio.open(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt')

rasterio.plot.show(raster_vrt)
```

Also, if I am opening this new `.vrt` file with QGIS its displaying the correct file combinations (file 1 & 3). So what I understood is the `.vrt` file has changed after running the `gdalbuildvrt` command but there is some problem while opening it with `rasterio` python because it's displaying old `.vrt` file (file 1 & 2).

Can someone help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: Could be a race condition, or some kind of file cache. To confirm, try give each combination of files a different VRT file name, rather than re-using `"D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt"`. If that's the case, then work on a different strategy for creating your VRTs, one that emphasises atomicity. e.g. write to a temporary file, then `move` (`mv` in Linux) the temporary file once it has been written and closed. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python This is to avoid prematurely reading a file that hasn't actually been (over-)written.

Comment: Thanks @RichardLaw for your kind suggestion. I just added raster_vrt.close() at the end of the program and the issue got resolved. Now I am able to overwrite the same vrt file with different file combinations.

Answer (score 2):

A [common idiom](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is to use a `with` statement when opening a file so that it is automatically closed when the `with` block is complete. To adapt the existing answer:

```
import rasterio 
import rasterio.plot

from osgeo import gdal

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
test_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt', [r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_58_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif', r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_60_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif'], options=vrt_options)

test_vrt = None

with rasterio.open(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt') as raster_vrt:

    rasterio.plot.show(raster_vrt)
```

Answer (score 1):

With kind suggestion from @Richard Law, adding raster_vrt.close() at the end of the program solved the issue....

```
import rasterio 
import rasterio.plot

from osgeo import gdal

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
test_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt', [r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_58_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif', r'D:\Test TIFF\Tile_60_LULC250k_2015_16_revised.tif'], options=vrt_options)

test_vrt = None

raster_vrt = rasterio.open(r'D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt')

rasterio.plot.show(raster_vrt)

raster_vrt.close()
```

Comment: You could also do `with rasterio.open('D:\Test TIFF\test.vrt') as vrt:` which would implicitly close the file when appropriate. This is a very common pattern in Python. http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Yup definitely that will be an another option as well.... :) Thanks @RichardLaw

Comment: @alphabetasoup please turn that into an answer so that we can vote it higher than this one ;)

Comment: @bugmenot123 done